# Загрузка страниц сайта. Двойной AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Столкнулась с такой вот проблемой! Делала подгрузку всех страниц сайта на AJAX, конечно же в начале указала `$(document).ready(function(){`, и все работает! Но проблема в том, что когда на подгруженную страницу, подгружаются новые данные, при переходе на которые должен срабатывать этотже AJAX запрос - он не срабатывает, а просто открывает все в новом окне, как будто этот скрипт к нему не относится! Подскажите как решить эту проблему ?!

Вот сам код, с исправленной версией на .on ( но не работает также для динамически появляющихся элементов ):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[rel~='x1']").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var handler = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({url:handler, cache:false,
                beforeSend :function() {
                    $('#x2').fadeIn();
                },
                success:function(html) {
                    $(".span8").html(html);
                    $('#x2').fadeOut();
                    window.history.replaceState('', '', handler);
                    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},"slow");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: попробую угадать... вы используете [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) а надо [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). оно?

Comment: да я использую click, проблема в этом ?!

Comment: Вот что было '$("a[rel~='x1']").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();'   Вот что стало и нечего не изменилось '$("a[rel~='x1']").on("click",function(e){
 e.preventDefault();'

Comment: Клик привязывается только к тем элементам, которые на момент привязки были на странице. Если нужно динамически обновлять клик, используйте .on, либо, в старых версиях, .live

Comment: jquery 1.8.2 используется, я использовал для динамики on как вы видите в комментарии выше, но все равно нечего не сработало! Сейчас добавлю к вопросу весь код AJAX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on` вешать надо не на сами элементы, а на родителя, который не будет у вас удаляться или перезаписываться. Например вешать можно на документ:

```
$(document).on("click","a[rel~='x1']", function(e){
  //....
});
```